# Minimal prime ideals and associated prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

I am currently self-reading the book 'Monomial Ideals' by Herzog-Hibi.
In lemma 1.3.5 of that book what is '$ P_j R_{p_i}$'?  I know what $R_{p_i}$ is. It is the localization at $p_i$. But I am confused about '$P_j R_{p_i}$'. 
Secondly in the proposition  1.3.7 what does the line ' f is regular on S/Q ' mean.
Thank you for your help! [image][image]

Comment: We don’t all have the book! It would be much more helpful if you wrote down the appropriate context.

Comment: I am really sorry. I have added pictures.

Comment: $P_jR_{P_i}$ is the ideal of $R_{P_i}$ generated by the elements of $P_j$. For your second question, I’m not sure what $S$ is.

Comment: S is the polynomial ring K[x1, x2,...xn]